# Access to global variables from a module in Python?

Tags: python, module, global-variables

let's start with a basic code that uses a global variable :

```
def fun():
    print(gvar)
gvar = 3

fun()
```

that of course prints "3" in the console.

Then, I move my function "fun" in a module "mymod", and do :

```
from mymod import *
gvar=3
fun()
```

The result is a NameError exception (`gvar` is not found)

How can I solve this ? I have to mention that I need to access to various global variables which name is not always the same (the context  is complex and I do not describe it now to focus on the problem I have for now)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only global variables python has, are module scoped. So in your case the variable `gvar` is not visible in the module `mymod`.

If you want to use `gvar` in an imported module, pass `gvar` as parameter to a function of `mymod`. If `gvar` belongs to `mymod`, define it there.

Answer (score 0):

Just move `gvar` into `mymod`. You don't even need to `import` it unless you need to access its value independently.

In other words, don't try to use `gvar` as a genuine global, but leave it as an implementation detail of `mymod`.

Comment: In the context in which I work it is not possible. I am looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this thing incorrectly, rather than making a variable into one script and trying to execute a function in another script using first variable, you can also **send the variable to function header of function**!!

#### So in your case your function will be like

```
def fun(var): 
    print(gvar)
```

#### And Call Your Function From Another Script With:

```
gvar = 5
fun(gvar)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it is not corresponding to my problem.